# "Singular noun + of + plural nouns + singular verb" confusion

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I've come across a sentence which says

> "The CEO of many corporations **is** responsible to the board that hired him"

notice the bold-faced part. Why can't we use "are" here?

Answer (score 1):

Simply because **the CEO** is singular.

It would also be fine to say:

> the **CEOs** of the companies **are** responsible...

It’s clear that each company has only one CEO.

Answer (score 0):

*The CEO of many corporations* - implies that, a single person is in charge of more than one corporation. If this is the case, then this sentence is fine. Otherwise, both the CEO (CEOs) and the to be verb would in plural (are).

Comment: While it could have that sense, I don't think that is the meaning used here. The original quote could be rewritten as "_In many corporations, the CEO is responsible..._" – where there is a 1-1 correspondence between CEOs and corporations.

Comment: @TripeHound I think, your guess is on point, however, can`t we say with the same meaning - CEOs of many corporations are responsible to the board that hired them ? Can the above-mentioned sentence be synonymous in meaning to this one - the CEO of many corporations is responsible to the board that hired him ?

Comment: I _think_ your first example would need to be "...to the board**s** that hired them" (which is basically David's answer). Otherwise, yes I think both are essentially the same.